# Panel of CSS-transition does not appear when hovering button

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

With the simple code below I want to run a **transition** in **CSS**. Once you hover over the `<button>` the `<panel>` should appear. However, currently when I hover over the `<button>` the `<panel>` item does not appear at all and I cannot find the issue in my code.

Do you see the mistake in my code why the transition is not working?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/6/)

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.button {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height:0px;
  transition: max-height .5s linear;
  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.button:hover .panel {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a mistake in your CSS. `.button:hover .panel` means `.panel` is a child of the button div. However, it is a sibling. Therefore you need to use a adjacent sibling selector (+).

`.button:hover + .panel` does the trick.

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.button {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height:0;
  transition: max-height .5s linear;
  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.button:hover + .panel {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, thanks for your help and the hint with the difference between the sibling and child relation. I also updated the code here https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/7/

Comment: @Michi Good luck with your project!

Comment: Additionally, I changed the menu to a version where the panel is the child of the button and the height is relative (%) here: https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/16/

Answer (score 0):

**please check this code i hope you will get your answer.**

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.button {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.panel {
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height:0px;
  transition: max-height .5s linear;
  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.button:hover, .panel:hover {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Menu</div> 
    
<div class="panel">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```